# mode() call does not work as expected in scipy/numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, mode

I run Python 3.6 in Windows 10.

I am using the train data found here: https://datahack.analyticsvidhya.com/contest/practice-problem-loan-prediction-iii/

I try to compute the mode of a column.  My code is:

```
from scipy.stats import mode
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('Loan3_train.csv')
mode(data['Gender'])[0]

This returns a warning and an exception:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:253: RuntimeWarning: The input array could not be properly checked for nan values. nan values will be ignored.
  "values. nan values will be ignored.", RuntimeWarning)

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

How can I understand these messages and address them?

Comment: There is a discussion on the website you link - explore the data first. Look out for things like 3+ in there.

Answer (score 0):

It's a datatype mismatch error! Mode expects column to be float and what you are passing is String. Use astype to convert Float to str like `data['Gender'] = data['Gender'].astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

From the error, some of the data is non-numeric.
There may also be null values in there too.

You need to find examples of the non-numeric data and process these.

You can use `df.applymap(np.isreal)` to find the problems.
When you have the offedning strings, you need to think a map to apply to these to make them numeric, if possible.

Alternatively, if you find you have data like "3+" or similar, you can treat it `astype('category')` to find the mode, provided you don't have nulls.